# How to rearrange a WinForms TabControl TabPages during design time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

How to reorder TabPages during design?

In a project of mine I don't mean to implement runtime reordering, but I'd like to place the pages in a specific meaningful order after initially designing them in another order.

Comment: Off the top of my head, the easiest way is the crack open the designer.cs (or designer.vb) file and change the order.

Comment: You've got a collection editor `[...]` and a PageIndex (or similar) property.

Comment: @henk-holterman, post the answer, I will accept it, you're right. There is the "TabPages" collection property editable this way.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the Properties window for your Tab Control, select the button with the ellipses:

[image: button to open TabPage Collection Editor]

You can add, remove, edit and reorder your Tab Pages in this editor:

[image: TabPage Collection Editor]

Comment: Keep in mind that rearranging the order of TabPages also requires changing the `SelectedIndex` values of the `TabControl` if you are using those values in your code.